# Localisation of MM/DD/YYYY prompt date letter abbreviations

Tags: dates

If a website is localised are users always going to understand that D = Day, M = Month even though these abbreviations are English abbreviations ? (global site, joe public users )

Comment: no, users from a non-English speaking country might not know what MM/DD/YYYY means.

Comment: @ChairmanMeow Do you have any further advice or suggested solutions for non-English localisations? This looks like a good start to an answer.

Comment: Related: [*DD/MM/YYYY - do people know what that means?*](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5058/dd-mm-yyyy-do-people-know-what-that-means/114777)

Answer (score 1):

An option to make this semantically clear would be to render a sample/ example near the date format selector. [day/month/ year : 06/04/2020] or [day/month/ year: 06/04/20] etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a calendar or select the day, month and year separately to avoid confusion.